# Confusing Python Multiprocessing Behavior

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get images from a USB camera.

Approach A:
If I access the camera directly using OpenCV like so:

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    status, img = cam.read()
    if status:
        cv2.imshow("Cam", img)
```

I get:
~3 FPS and all 8 cores of my computer are running at 100%

Approach B:
If I instead run this as a separate Process using Python's multiprocessing library and pass the values back to the main function as a multiprocessing Queue like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Queue
import cv2
def run(lock, queue, cam):
    while True:
        status, img = cam.read()
        if status:
            with lock:
                queue.put(img)
                if queue.qsize() > 10:
                    queue.get() # This is to prevent massive queue size
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
lock = Lock()
queue = Queue()
p = Process(target = run, args = (lock, queue, cam)
p.start()
while True:
    with lock:
        if queue.qsize() > 0:
            img = queue.get()
            if img is not None:
                cv2.imshow("cam", img)
```

I get:
~8 FPS and only 1 core of my computer is running at 100%. All other cores are near 0%.

But what's weirdest to me, is if I first run this as a separate process (Approach B) and then, in the same program, access the camera directly (Approach A) like so:

```
#Approach B
#Release B's connection to the camera
#Terminate and join B's process
#Approach A
```

I get:
~13 FPS and only 1 core of my computer is running at near 100%. All other cores are near 0%.

So, how do I get that final ~13 FPS using only one core without having to first create and destroy the then unnecessary Process? I'd attribute the ~8 FPS of Approach B alone to conflicting Locks. But I don't understand why Approach A isn't 13 FPS from the start.

Thanks!

For context, this is running on an 8-core ARM processor running Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Your second example only ever shows one image, and only if the initial qsize check doesn't fail, the rest of the images are discarded in your worker because `queue.qsize > 10` evalueates to `True` (you're comparing the method, not its return value, which on python3 would raise an exception). I'm not sure sharing the cam object between multiple processes is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @mata ! I was trying to simplify much more complicated code for easier reference here in SO and had missed a few key parts.

You're absolutely correct, I had just neglected to include the 'while true' and the '()' at the end of 'qsize'.

Regarding sharing cameras, I definitely learned not to do that. In my description I also forgot to mention that I am releasing the camera connection when switching between Approach B and Approach A. This is critical or else the camera won't respond at all.

Updated the initial post accordingly.

Comment: A multiprocessing approach also would mean that all the data from the camera has to be pickled and sent between processes using pipes, which isn't really the fastest way. I'm quite positive OpenCV releases the GIL when doing calls implemented in C/C++, so using multiprocessing probably won't give you more speed, multithreading might be the better option here.

Comment: Thanks again @mata - That makes sense, but from my testing, if I build it using threading as opposed to multiprocessing then it uses all 8 cores at 100% but still only gets 3 FPS.

It seems as though running a Process, any Process, forces the entire main program to run on a single core. Then the difference between the ~8 FPS of Approach B and the ~13 FPS of B+A is just because there are no Lock conflicts in the B+A approach.

Comment: Where did your measurements indentify the bottleneck -- `cam.read(...)` or `cv.imshow(...)`? My guess would be the latter.

Comment: Hey @DanMašek - I just went through and calculated everything. Approach A: Overall - 0.3 sec. cam.read() - 0.16 sec. cv2.imshow() - 0.1 sec. Approach B: Overall - 0.125 sec. cam.read() - 0.055 sec. queue.get() - 0.11sec. cv2.imshow() - 0.036 sec. Approach B+A: Overall - 0.077 sec. cam.read() - 0.048 sec. cv2.imshow() - 0.029 sec. ---- Based on these results it looks like BOTH cam.read() and cv2.imshow() have 3x processing time using Approach A.